# ServiceNow Add Record form : Mandatory fields missing alert is showing in even after filling values

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I have a client script in onLoad incident forms which adds a popup on click of a particular button (which I am adding through script).

When I am trying to add an incident record by filling all mandatory fields , click on the button which add popup html and then click on submit it says mandatory fields are missing.

This is happening in any scenario where I render extra html through client script.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (event.target.classList.contains("searchEMCIs")) {
        alert("clicked");
                if (document.contains(document.getElementById("emSearchPopup")))
                    document.getElementById("emSearchPopup").remove();
               var popupHtml = "";
popupHtml += '<div id="emSearchPopup" style="width: 100%;height: 50%;border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;background: #fff;z-index: 2;">';
popupHtml += '</div>';
                document.querySelector("div.section-content").innerHTML += popupHtml;
            }
});
```

Comment: Can you add the details so I can recreate this on my PDI in a minimum verifiable example?

- Is the above code in a UI action, or as you say on a client script.
- If it's just a client script, what are the details of the button, so I can create that and add this script.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Mine is a client script, which I am calling onLoad of Incident form, the button I am rendering in the same script. I will add a sample minimal script for the whole process

Comment: I was appending the element to a div with section-content class, now I changed it to append to a div with input_controls class, its working fine now

Comment: Yea, using a client script to add a button, unless it needs to exist in a non-conventional place, doesnt make sense to me.  I would recomend making a UI Action, and having that be client-side.  But I'm glad you got it working in whatvever form you needed.